# Why would the Filter formula only give the "No Match" result when there' clearly a match?

Tags: filter, excel-formula

I'm trying to produce a dynamic list of item numbers based on a yes/no answer from a table in the second sheet in the workbook. If the word "YES" is present in a row (Available) I want to add the item number (ITEM #), if the word "NO" is present I want it to skip over and go to the next row. I have gotten the formula to the point where it functions but is only returning the No Match result.

Notes: The second table name is Internal Data. The result will be in in the table on the sheet named "FINAL" and shouldn't affect the formulas in the rest of the cells. The formula is written in the bar as well as on here. [[Here's pics of both tables]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOJQB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rQv3.png)

I have tried various alterations of both the legacy and current formulas below.

Legacy: =AGGREGATE(15,3,(InternalData[@[AVAILABLE]]="YES")/(InternalData[@[AVAILABLE]]="YES")*(ROW(InternalData[@[AVAILABLE]]="yes")-ROW($M$6)),ROWS($U$6:U7))

Current: =FILTER(InternalData[AVAILABLE],(InternalData[ITEM '#])="YES","No Match")

It seems the current formula is better and less error prone. I was expecting the item # on line 5 of "FINAL" to return the value "30620" but I'm only getting "No Match"

Comment: So you want to have the results by row or all at once? Do both sheets contain actual tables or only one? In what cell can we find your formula? The aggregate version you shared, does that give you the desired result? And last but definitely not least: please post data as data, not as screenshot. Please use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to create a postable format.

Comment: The formula *should be* `=FILTER(InternalData[ITEM '#],InternalData[AVAILABLE]="YES","No Match")` but even that will produce an error, as you cannot have a formula which spills, in an Excel table

Comment: @P.b In My mind it would produce the entire list without manually sorting and copying from the second sheet. The aggregate method did not work for me. And thanks for the heads up on how to post table data. I'll work on learning that this week.